# По свойству color в CSS не меняется цвет текста в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html, css

```
<textarea class="textarea" placeholder=" message"></textarea>​
```

-

```
.textarea {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
    color: green;
    display: block;
    font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    width: 290px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vw6aU/2/

Comment: Быть такого не может. наверняка допускаете ошибки в коде или что-то упустили. Предоставите код, вам помогут разобраться :)

Comment: Код в студию.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vw6aU/

Comment: у меня меняется color на зеленый. placeholder - это прошлый век)

Comment: вв FF все ок. в Хроме не меняется у меня

Comment: Chrome 21.0.1180.79 все прекрасно работает. Где вы там проблему то нашли?

Comment: а про placeholder - использовал первое что нашел. если подстажете можный вариант, буду только благодарен

Comment: http://i002.radikal.ru/1209/23/f8dfec2a1ab5.png

Comment: @chelovechki 
Видимо вам что-то типа такого надо http://jsfiddle.net/mqa8M/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:green;
}
```

[more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)